# how to get the rest of the positions on my position table

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone I am trying to get the full count on my table because right now it is showing only one position instead of 5 if anyone can help that would really be appreciated

`select position_name, state,count(*) -> from positions -> join employees on (employees.position_id = positions.position_id) -> ;`

I am trying to get a table count of all the positions in each state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `position_name` and `state` to get each count

```
select p.position_name, p.state, count(*)
from positions p
join employees e on e.position_id = p.position_id
group by p.position_name, p.state
```